# Crossfade many audio files into one with FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, cross-fade

Using FFmpeg, I am trying to combine many audio files into one long one, with a crossfade between each of them. To keep the numbers simple, let's say I have 10 input files, each 5 minutes, and I want a 10 second crossfade between each. (Resulting duration would be 48:30.) Assume all input files have the same codec/bitrate.

I was pleasantly surprises to find how simple it was to crossfade *two* files:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mp3 -i 1.mp3 -vn -filter_complex acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri out.mp3
```

But the `acrossfade` filter does not allow 3+ inputs. So my naive solution is to repeatedly run `ffmpeg`, crossfading the previous intermediate output with the next input file. It's not ideal. It leads me to two questions:

**1. Does `acrossfade` losslessly copy the streams?** (Except where they're actively crossfading, of course.) **Or do the entire input streams get reencoded?**

If the input streams are entirely reencoded, then my naive approach is very bad. In the example above (calling `acrossfade` 9 times), the first 4:50 of the first file would be reencoded 9 times! If I'm combining 50 files, the first file gets reencoded 49 times!

**2. To avoid multiple runs and the reencoding issue, can I achieve the many-crossfade behavior in a single `ffmpeg` call?**

I imagine I would need some long filtergraph, but I haven't figured it out yet. Does anyone have an example of crossfading just 3 input files? From that I could automate the filtergraphs for longer chains.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: what if you cut each audio file into three parts ... you crossfade the first with the last of previous file ... just append the middle file then repeat ... my guess is the act of appending not require recoding

Comment: It's discouraged to crosspost [the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/1363461/crossfade-many-audio-files-into-one-with-ffmpeg) to multiple Stack Exchange sites. It tends to waste effort. Anyway, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: Of course. I promise my original intent was not to crosspost, but immediately after posting this I discovered that StackOverflow covers ffmpeg library questions, and SuperUser covers ffmpeg commandline program questions. Should I delete this post here?